# Grouping results in a specific order

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm stuck with a MySQL query. At first, I thought it would be an easy job, but it's turned into something I just can't get over.

I have a table such as:

```
ID_USER  ID_LESSON  TITLE
   1        1       Maths
   1        2       Geography
   1        3       History
   2        4       Spanish
   2        5       Maths
   2        6       English
```

I need to get result such as:

```
ID_USER  ID_LESSON  TITLE
   1        2       Geography
   2        6       English
```

Basicly, what I need to get is one row for each user where is subject title ordered ascendantly.

I tried a query like

```
SELECT id_user, id_lesson, title FOM table 
GROUP BY id_user ORDER BY title ASC
```

But the problem was, that even if I got just one row for each user, the title in the result was not right (because when I used GROUP BY command, the result was ordered by id_lesson)

I have a feeling that the solution maybe quite simple but I cant break it down.

I'll be happy for any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: When using `GROUP BY`, you can't make any assumptions about the values for any non-grouped columns. In your case, when the `GROUP BY` is applied, `TITLE` will take on the value of one of the rows for that value of `id_user`. Then the `ORDER BY` clause will be applied on the resulting grouped data. You can't specify which `TITLE` will be chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM your_table t1
WHERE t1.title = 
    (SELECT title FROM your_table
     WHERE id_user = t1.id_user
     ORDER BY title
     LIMIT 1)
```